# Running into error - all go routines are asleep error when implementing a lexer in golang

Tags: go, compiler-construction, lexer

I'm trying to write a scanner/lexer in go, I thought I'd figure it out and after attempting to implement I ran into the error mentioned in the title. Any advice?

Essentially, I'm trying to implement a scanner based on the information from Rob Pike's talk at the Go conference in 2011. He talks about using a finite state machine to implement a scanner in a way that's similar to this:

type state func(s *Scanner) state

basically a recursive structure, in my state implementation, in my emit function I'm trying to print out details about the tokens being received.

```
    package scanner

/*
A scanner initializes itself to scan a string/file, then launches a goroutine
that returns the scanner and a channel of items to be tokenized! 
*/
import (
    t "CPRL/token"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
    // "unicode"
)

//Scanner - performs lexical analysis

    type Scanner struct {
        CH rune //character examined

        FILE  string //the name of our current file, used for error reporting
        input string //the string currently being scanned

        start int //start position of our token
        curr  int //current position in input
        line  int //current line we are scanning
        width int //the size of last rune read

        tokens chan t.Token //channel of scanned tokens!

    }


    func (s Scanner) String() string {
        var str []string

        if s.FILE != "" {
            str = append(str, s.FILE+": ")
        }

        return strings.Join(str, "")
    }

//Scan - create a new scanner for current input
func Scan(File string) *Scanner {
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(File)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    in := string(buf)
    s := &Scanner{
        FILE:   File,
        input:  in,
        line:   1,
        tokens: make(chan t.Token),
    }
    go s.Init()
    return s
}

//Init - initialize a created a scanner

    func (s *Scanner) Init() {
        for state := scanTo; state != nil; {
            state = state(s)
            fmt.Println("State entered")
        }
    }
```

I'm attempting to print all the tokens as strings with code that looks like this, in another package

```
for tok := range t.Tokens {
  fmt.Println(tok.String())
}
```

Here, we have the slides from Rob Pike's talk at go conference:
https://talks.golang.org/2011/lex.slide#1

This is the project I'm working on currently.
https://github.com/Apheuz/CPRL

Comment: The problem is likely to be found where tokens channel is used, which you did not include here.

Comment: @Burak is right, you have not given enough code (and info).  For example, I can't work out what or where `scanTo` is.  Maybe also add a link to Rob Pike's talk.

Comment: @AJR thank you guys for your comments, would you mind taking a look at the code through the github link? I'm still banging my head over why I'm running into this error since I'm pretty new to using go.

Comment: Put code into [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XvuPd79vxH8) - but needs some work to tidy up!. I assume you are trying to run ```scanner.Scan``` (differs slightly from your code above). If so the first issue is that ```s.tokens``` is never closed so ```for tok := range s.Tokens ``` will never exit (leading to the deadlock as that will be the last thing running).

Answer (score 0):

channels are blocking.

your call to

```
for tok := range s.tokens
```

will block, until someone is writing to the channel or closing it..

but no one will!

Comment: Hmm I tried calling close(s.tokens) to close the channels when scanning EOF, however that lead to me being unable to retrieve the tokens from the channel

Comment: would be great if you could create a small playground (including "data" in a string maybe) to reproduce that behavior